# Loop Through an Indexed Array

Tags: php

I'm creating my little booking system and I'm trying to set a date to current week.
Could someone explain why the code below isn't working?

```
$lastWeek = [];
$arrlength=count($lastWeek);
$lastWeek[0] = date('D',strtotime('last monday'));
$lastWeek[1] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +1day'));
$lastWeek[2] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +2day'));
$lastWeek[3] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +3day'));
$lastWeek[4] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +4day'));

echo "<html><head><title>Event Booking timetable</title></head>";
echo "<body><table id=myTable border=2>";
echo "<tr><td>Week Commencing</td>";

for ($x=0; $x<$arrlength; $x++)
{
echo "<td>";
echo $lastWeek[$x];
echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: You are setting `$arrlength` before you fill the array. Don't use incremental `for` loops in PHP, except in the most exotic circumstances. [Use `foreach` most of the time](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).  `foreach($lastWeek as $day) { echo $day; }`

Comment: sorted my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
// declare vars
$lastWeek  = array();
$arrlength = 0;

// set vars
$lastWeek[0] = date('D',strtotime('last monday'));
$lastWeek[1] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +1day'));
$lastWeek[2] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +2day'));
$lastWeek[3] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +3day'));
$lastWeek[4] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +4day'));

$arrlength = count($lastWeek); // count after set $lastWeek!

// Print result
echo "<html><head><title>Event Booking timetable</title></head>";
echo "<body><table id=myTable border=2>";
echo "<tr><td>Week Commencing</td>";

for ($x=0; $x<$arrlength; $x++)
{
    echo "<td>";
    echo $lastWeek[$x];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$arrlength=count($lastWeek);
```

this must be set after you add your items or else it will be 0

Answer (score 2):

You're counting the length of the array before filling it. Also, you're not closing your table and rows the right way. This should work:

```
$lastWeek = [];
$lastWeek[0] = date('D',strtotime('last monday'));
$lastWeek[1] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +1day'));
$lastWeek[2] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +2day'));
$lastWeek[3] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +3day'));
$lastWeek[4] = date('D',strtotime('last monday +4day'));
$arrlength = count($lastWeek);

echo "<html><head><title>Event Booking timetable</title></head>";
echo "<body><table id=myTable border=2>";
echo "<tr><td>Week Commencing</td></tr>";

for ($x=0; $x<$arrlength; $x++)
{
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $lastWeek[$x];
echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```